# ARCore: Raw Depth Codelab is not working on my phone

Tags: shader, android-camera, arcore, google-codelab

I wanted to test this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/arcore-rawdepthapi#0) from Google, but whenever I try to run the part3_completed file/application on my Huawei P30 ELE-L29 phone, I encounter the following errors (from logcat):

```
2022-05-13 12:41:47.466 27231-27231/? E/odelab.rawdept: LoadAppImageStartupCache enabled : 1
2022-05-13 12:41:47.466 27231-27231/? E/odelab.rawdept: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-05-13 12:41:47.500 27231-27251/com.google.ar.core.codelab.rawdepth E/BehaviorCollectManager: Fail to acquire dataAnalyzerService...
2022-05-13 12:41:47.568 27231-27272/com.google.ar.core.codelab.rawdepth E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@20b4461
2022-05-13 12:41:47.692 27231-27277/com.google.ar.core.codelab.rawdepth E/DepthRenderer: Error compiling shader: 0:56: L0002: Undeclared variable 'f'
    0:57: L0002: Undeclared variable 'f'
    0:58: L0002: Undeclared variable 'kMinHeightMeters'
    0:59: L0002: Undeclared variable 'normalizedHeight'
2022-05-13 12:41:47.694 27231-27277/com.google.ar.core.codelab.rawdepth E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1080
    Process: com.google.ar.core.codelab.rawdepth, PID: 27231
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating shader.
        at com.google.ar.core.codelab.common.rendering.ShaderUtil.loadGLShader(ShaderUtil.java:53)
        at com.google.ar.core.codelab.common.rendering.DepthRenderer.createOnGlThread(DepthRenderer.java:67)
        at com.google.ar.core.codelab.rawdepth.RawDepthCodelabActivity.onSurfaceCreated(RawDepthCodelabActivity.java:208)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1560)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1281)
```

You can clone the sample code through `git clone https://github.com/googlecodelabs/arcore-rawdepthapi` to check it out yourself.

I'm confused because I didn't change anything in the sample code and I was expecting it to work on my phone since it supports Depth API. I've tried a [different depth codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/arcore-depth#0) from Google and it worked but this one somehow doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to fix the issue by removing the 'f' at the end of the float assignments for kMinHeightMeters and normalizedHeight. The app works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution above fixed it for me too. I removed the "f" from the kMinHeightMeters and kMaxHeightMeters in the depth_point_cloud.vert file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).